# draw a circular progress view which shows range

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, core-graphics

A circular view will show progress as you can see I have pointed out, the circular view should be divided in ranges and will show a progress how much percent is reached. 
[image]

I don't know how to approach with this design and how to divide the view in equal range and shows how much progress user has achieved.

Any suggestion and help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I already made it clear in the question, I think you missed it ---- " I don't know how to approach with this design , need help on this."

Comment: Hint: ProgressView  ,play with that ,check examples on net .Thats how you learn .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two CAShapeLayer,one as background,one as progress

Example

[image]

```
-(CAShapeLayer *)createCircleWithBounds:(CGRect)bounds
                           Position:(CGPoint)position
                        StrokeColor:(UIColor*)color
                          LineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth
{
CAShapeLayer* shapelayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapelayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
shapelayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
shapelayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds cornerRadius:CGRectGetWidth(bounds)/2].CGPath;
shapelayer.bounds = bounds;
shapelayer.position = position;
shapelayer.lineCap = kCALineCapButt;
shapelayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
return shapelayer;
}
```

Then

```
 CAShapeLayer * progressLayer = [self createCircleWithBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) Position:self.view.center StrokeColor:[UIColor whiteColor] LineWidth:5.0];
progressLayer.strokeStart = 0.2;
progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.8;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:progressLayer];

CAShapeLayer * otherLayer = [self createCircleWithBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) Position:self.view.center StrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor] LineWidth:5.0];
otherLayer.strokeStart = 0.2;
otherLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:otherLayer];
```

Then what you need to do is just use some math function to change the `otherLayer.strokeEnd`  when the progress change

Comment: If you want your updated image,you may use a image or gradient layer as background.Then use CAShaper layer to set maskLayer

Comment: Due to some copyright issue I have removed that.Actually my need was the previous image.I going through your approach, lets see how far i can get.

Comment: How to add border in both the layer?/ is this possible

Answer (score -1):

You can use `CAShapeLayer` and `CGPath` to programatically draw it.